# How to show an array of data objects in flatlist react native?

Tags: react-native

How to render an array of data objects in flatlist react native?
here is the list data

```
const ListItem = [
  {

    'a5ab17kjsnx6179qoprea': {
      name: 'crystal',
      number: 1,
    },
    'b2ab1bc20kjsnx6179qoa': {
      name: 'barba',
      number: 2,
    },
  },
];
```

i tried this below but noting is showing

```
 <FlatList
        data={Object.keys(ListItem)}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{ListItem[item].name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{ListItem[item].number}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
```

Comment: Please follow this documentation. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist
and on https://react-native-elements.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/listitem.html#using-rn-flatlist-implemented-with-link-and-avatar

Answer (score 0):

Object.keys works on Object not Array but

```
Object.keys(ListItem) // ListItem is an Array
```

whereas,

```
Object.keys(ListItem(0)) //returns [ 'a5ab17kjsnx6179qoprea',''b2ab1bc20kjsnx6179qoa']
```

so this should work now and give a try to a code below

```
 <FlatList
        data={Object.keys(ListItem(0))}
        renderItem={({ item }) => {
          return (
            <View>
              <View>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{ListItem[0][item].name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 16 }}>{ListItem[0][item].number}</Text>
              </View>
            </View>
          );
        }}
      />
```

Answer (score -1):

Just change this

```
data={Object.keys(ListItem)}
```

To this

```
data={Object.keys(ListItem[0])}
```

and access items like this ListItem[0][item].name and ListItem[0][item].number instead of doing ListItem[item].name etc.